# Does Windows 10 add hidden properties/metadata to files? If yes, what data is added and can it be deleted?

Tags: windows-10, security, privacy, metadata

I understand that if you right-click on a file and navigate to the "Details" tab, you can view a list of properties such as "Date created", "Date modified", "Owner", etc.

My question is whether this encompasses **all** of the data that exists on the file, or whether Windows neglects showing any hidden metadata in this view.

More specifically, I am wondering:

- Is there a CLI command or some other way to view all data on any
  arbitrary file?
- If there is hidden metadata, is it possible to be removed? How?

FYI, I am asking about all files **in general** (i.e. **not** pertaining to a specific file-type).

Also, I know you can "Remove Properties and Personal Information" using the previously referenced interface, but I am wondering if there is data outside of this scope that exists on the file (and wouldn't be deleted even if I did attempt to remove the data in this fashion).

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from what you listed, NTFS can also store the following metadata:

- File ACLs (mostly what you see in the "Security" tab). What's invisible is that the ACLs store your Windows user account's SID – not the username – and for local accounts the SID is *usually* unique to your computer. (However, there's no way to find a username or its computer knowing only a SID.)
- Alternate data streams – basically acting as alternate "contents" for the file. If present, can be seen using `dir /r` or many other tools. Very rarely used by modern Windows, except for a very generic "this file came from Internet" marker. (However, Windows XP *did* allow you to enter custom metadata for any file in the same Properties tab you mention, and stored them in that file's ADS.) Other applications such as Dropbox might also put their own stuff in ADS.
- OS/2 Extended Attributes. Never used for anything at all.

Note that **all** Windows-managed metadata is external – it does not persist if a copying tool simply reads from one file and writes to another. (Most copy programs still transfer useful metadata such as modification time or ACLs, but that's a deliberate action on their part.)

Also note that none of the above metadata can be stored on FAT32/exFAT filesystems. Windows will copy files into a FAT flashdrive without their ACLs, and it'll just warn you if it has to discard any ADS.